# Can Fragments be used in an Activity that extends from base class that inherits from FragmentActivity?

Tags: android

I have   MyActivity extends MyBaseActivity which in tern extends Activity. If my BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity is that all that is needed for MyActivity to use Fragements or is more refactoring needed?

Answer (score 2):

If you have this:

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends FragmentActivity{}
public class MyActivity extends MyBaseActivity{}
```

Yes, MyActivity can use fragments.

Answer (score 0):

FragmentActivity If MyBaseActivity extends FragmentActivity, then MyActivity can use fragments.

You use FragmentActivity when using Android Compatibility Package on a pre-API11 device, so you should also include android.support.v4 in libs directory.